# Should synchronization happen in the member class or in the wrapper class?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

First, what I've read through:

- [In Java critical sections, what should I synchronize on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/416183)
- [synchronized(this) blocks whole object? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11981227)
- [Does thread.yield() lose the lock on object if called inside a synchronized method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10679676)
- [What is the difference between a synchronized method and synchronized block in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1149928)
- [Java synchronized difference threading [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10185867)
- [What is the difference between a synchronized function and synchronized block?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8519700)

And I followed the myriad links to duplicates listed on most of those posts. So I apologize ahead of time if this is a duplicate. I don't feel my question was answered by any of those, or the subsequent links. But then again, I am asking now because I have no clue as to what is going on here. Now on to the main event...

I have a pair of classes, `A` and `B`. Class `B` has an instance of `A` as a member:

Class A:

```js
public class A {
    private final int count;

    public A(int val) {
        count = val;
    }

    public int count() { return count; }

    public A incrementCount() {
        return new A(count + 1);
    }

    public void doStuff(long i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i * 100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Class B:

```js
public class B implements Runnable{
    private A a;

    public B() { a = new A(0); }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                a.doStuff(i);
                a = a.incrementCount();
            }
    }
}
```

And I have a class that takes an instance of B and passes it to two threads, starts both threads, and then lets them do their thing:

```js
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        Thread b1 = new Thread(b, "b1");
        b1.start();
        Thread b2 = new Thread(b, "b2");
        b2.start();
        try {
            b1.join();
            b2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I expect is, for the instance of A contained by `b`, `count` to increment from 0 to 8, sequentially.

But for this code:

```js
synchronized public A incrementCount() {
     return new A(count + 1);
}

synchronized public void doStuff(long i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(i * 100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or this code (equivalent to above I think):

```js
public A incrementCount() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return new A(count + 1);
    }
}

public void doStuff(long i) {
    synchronized (this){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i * 100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get results like this:

```js
THREAD|    OBJECT     |COUNT
----------------------------
main  |testbed.A@11121|  0    
b1    |testbed.A@64f6c|  1    
b1    |testbed.A@87238|  2    
b2    |testbed.A@2bb51|  2    
b2    |testbed.A@17d5d|  3    
b1    |testbed.A@16fa4|  4    
b2    |testbed.A@95c08|  4    
b1    |testbed.A@191d8|  5    
b2    |testbed.A@2d9c0|  5
```

Clearly, something is amiss. I also think it is worth noting that the objects all appear to be unique objects, even though there are duplicate numbers.

But for this code (in Class A):

```js
private final Object incrementLock = new Object();
private final Object doStuffLock = new Object();

...

public A incrementCount() {
    synchronized (incrementLock) {
        return new A(count + 1);
    }
}

public void doStuff(long i) {
    synchronized (doStuffLock){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i * 100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Or this code (in Class B):

```js
@Override
synchronized public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        a.doStuff(i);
        a = a.incrementCount();
    }
}
```

I get the results I expect:

```js
THREAD|    OBJECT       |COUNT
------------------------------
main  |testbed.A@f7f540 |  0    
b1    |testbed.A@64f6cd |  1    
b2    |testbed.A@872380 |  2    
b1    |testbed.A@2bb514 |  3    
b2    |testbed.A@17d5d2a|  4    
b1    |testbed.A@16fa474|  5    
b2    |testbed.A@95c083 |  6    
b1    |testbed.A@191d8c1|  7    
b2    |testbed.A@2d9c06 |  8
```

Since there is only a single object being accessed by both threads (`b1` and `b2`), why aren't `synchronized (this)` or `synchronized public...` locking the object instance, preventing both threads from entering the synchronized blocks and corrupting `count`, so to speak? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should synchronize the code in `B`, where you have multiple threads mutating the state (instance variable `a`). It does not make sense to synchronize methods in `A`, because instances of the class are really just immutable value objects.

When synchronizing methods on `this` in `A`, the most problematic part in the code is this:

```
a = a.incrementCount();
```

because there you leak the monitor outside of the class and re-assign the variable that's holding it.

Even though the version of `A` that uses different monitor objects for both methods seems to work, there is a race condition (which you could see if you add more threads and iteration steps and reduce/eliminate the sleep time in `doStuff()`) because nothing guarantees that the correctly incremented `a` got assigned in the above code.

The only way to make your code thread-safe is to synchronize the `run()` method in `B`.

Comment: Is there any chance I could convince you to elaborate on what you mean by *...leak the monitor outside of the class*?

Answer (score 0):

In `incrementCount()` you create each time a new instance of `A` which pretty much compromises your whole idea of synchronization. This is your problem here. Just increment the counter, don't replace/recreate the `A` instance each time.